# Passing SQL query into JS array for Google Maps

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, arrays

I want to map a field, city, from a MySQL database into Google Maps. I found a nice script here, but haven't been able to get it to work.

If I hard code an array into locations (var locations = ['Seattle', 'New York']), it works fine. Passing this SQL array into JS is giving me problems.

I've tried a number of different things, but I'm stuck. Right now I'm trying getElementById, but no dice. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

```
<?php
$server_name="localhost";
$db_user="sql_user";
$db_pass="password";
$db="mydb";

mysql_connect($server_name, $db_user, $db_pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

$sql = "SELECT city FROM posts";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Query Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $city[] = $results;
}

?>



<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div> 

  <script type="text/javascript"> 

    var locations = document.getElementById("<?=$city?>");

    var mapOpt = { 
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.00, -100.00),
       zoom: 3
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOpt);

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var index = 0;

    var geocoderFunction = function () { 
       geocoder.geocode({ 'address': locations[index] }, function (results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: results[0].geometry.location
             });             
          }

          // Call the geocoder with a 100ms delay
          index++;
          if (locations.length > index) {
             setTimeout(geocoderFunction, 100);
          }
       });
    }

    // Launch the geocoding process
    geocoderFunction();
  </script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this is supposed to do. Is the `document.getElementById("<?=$city?>")` some kind of special PHP syntax? Are you trying to assign the PHP array `$city` to the JavaScript variable `locations`?

Answer (score 1):

Like the name suggests, `mysql_fetch_array` returns an `Array`, not a `String`. Since you put those arrays in an array (`$city`), what you get (`$city`) is an array with arrays. JSON and json_encode are fine with that, but it's not what you want.

What you want:

```
var locations = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"];
```

What you get:

```
var locations = [["aa"], ["bb"], ["cc"], ["dd"]];
```

or maybe

```
var locations = [{"city":"aa"}, {"city":"bb"}, {"city":"cc"}, {"city":"dd"}];
```

or a combination of those :)

How you fix that:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM) ) {
    $city[] = $row[0];
}
```

Also: json_encode returns its value. It doesn't alter its argument by reference. So just `json_encode(..)` won't do anything. Try:

```
$city = json_encode($city);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call json_encode($city) to convert the array from a PHP object to a javascript readable format.  Use JSON.parse in the javascript to convert that string into a javascript array.

Answer (score 0):

That makes sense. So at the top of the file I now have:

```
$sql = "SELECT gender FROM posts";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Query Error: ' . mysql_error());
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM) ) {
    $city[] = $row[0];
}

$city = json_encode($city);

?>

  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var locations = JSON.parse($city);
```

But alas, this results in a blank page. Something in the syntax is off...but what? It looks fine to me.

Comment: How did you get from `city` to `gender` in your sql query? =)

Answer (score 0):

You should still print the `$city` var, so the PHP contents are printed into HTML instead of the string '$city':

```
var locations = JSON.parse($city);
```

Check the source of the page (CTRL+U) to see PHP's output. The blank page might be because of the Javascript syntax error =)

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I was able to just use `<?=$city_text?>;` and then do an implode (`$city_text = "['" . implode("','", $city) . "']";`) to get the array to pass correctly. Thank you!